# What Language and Graphics Library is CLion made in?

Tags: clion

I was wondering what language the CLion IDE was written in, and what Library is used to make the graphics for it.

Answer (score 4):

[See this wiki post.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains)

Written in Java

Comment: what graphics library though?

Answer (score 1):

It's written in Java using Swing.